# Adding Web API to existing ASP.NET Web Forms application only works from internal AJAX calls

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, webforms

I'm having some troubles accessing my WebApi in an asp.net WebForms app.

I followed the Microsoft article here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/using-web-api-with-aspnet-web-forms

When I access the API from Default.aspx using a client-side AJAX request using jQuery, **everything works fine**.

```
function getProducts() {
    $.getJSON("api/products",
        function (data) {

            // Loop through the list of products.
            $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                var msg = 'Name: ' + val.Name + ' - Price: ' + val.Price;
                alert(msg);
            });
        });
}

$(document).ready(getProducts);
```

**Issue**

However, when trying to access the same endpoint using Postman, all I get is the HTML for my website instead of JSON.

**Question**

How can I access my WebAPI using Postman?

[image: postman screenshot]

In Global.asax.cs, Application_Start I added the following:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
```

In my website project, I added a new Web API Controller Class (v2.1), which was placed inside the root directory's App_Code folder.

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    Product[] products = new Product[]
    {
        new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Tomato Soup", Category = "Groceries", Price = 1 },
        new Product { Id = 2, Name = "Yo-yo", Category = "Toys", Price = 3.75M },
        new Product { Id = 3, Name = "Hammer", Category = "Hardware", Price = 16.99M }
    };

    public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
    {
        return products;
    }

    public Product GetProductById(int id)
    {
        var product = products.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
        if (product == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        return product;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Product> GetProductsByCategory(string category)
    {
        return products.Where(
            (p) => string.Equals(p.Category, category,
                StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Yes and No. I figured out what the issue was but don't have a good solution so I abandoned this approach. My Web Forms application uses Forms Authentication. So when a request comes into the web api, the HTML that was being returned was from my login page. It wanted me to authenticate. The reason why the jQuery AJAX request was working was because I was already authenticated at that point. When a user is authenticated, they get a cookie set in their browser. If I copied that cookie (in F12 Chrome tools), and set it as a header in Postman, then everything worked fine. But that's not a solution